# ERROR when creating Drupal Project with DDEV: "Existing settings.php file includes settings.ddev.php Ensuring write permissions for folder "

Tags: docker, macos, ddev, colima

I am using Mac and I'm trying to open a Drupal project. I'm using "ddev composer create "drupal/recommended-project" --no-install" command and get a permissions error every time. It doesn't matter if I am using Colima or Ddev.
I gave the project folder Chmod -R 777 and got "Existing settings.php file includes settings.ddev.php Ensuring write permissions for folder" error. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Existing settings.php file includes settings.ddev.php 
Ensuring write permissions for folder
```

is not an error at all. It's simple informational output telling you two things:

1. Your settings.php file has already been set up to include settings.ddev.php
2. DDEV is making your sites/default directory and sites/default/settings.php writeable. (Drupal has always had the annoying habit of making those read-only, even for the owner of the files, which is painful for local development.

So you don't have an error at all! If there is more output that you'd like to discuss, update your post and mention in a comment.

It's certainly possible that that output (which has been the same for 5 years I think) should just be debug output, and not shown all the time.

Comment: Thank you for this note, @rfay! Finally, I got my Drupal installed.

Comment: In your honor I turned that into debug output @EvilArgest, https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/4334 - glad it's working for you!